# como passar parametro para outra tela com ionic1 e angular1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Eu criei uma tela com vários botões muito parecida com essa :

https://plus.google.com/+JoshuaMorony/posts/Rjhs4RCwek3

Quando clico em um botão ele teria um id e esse id eu recebo na rota dele, eu fiz com lista já, mas vários botões passando parâmetro ainda não consegui.

A minha dúvida é como passar esse id do botão para outra tela.

Avisos.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Avisos">
  <ion-content style="background-color: #FF4500; background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;">
    <div class="row icon-row">
            <div class="col text-center">
              <button class="botao button button-positive" id="1">Icon</button>
              <br>mais informaçoes
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center">
              <button class="botao button button-positive" id="2">Icon</button>
              <br>Avisos
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center ">
              <button class="botao button button-positive" id="3">Icon</button>
              <br>Contato
            </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Nessa parte é onde eu recebo o id, Como posso receber nessa parte o id do button escolhido ? e passar ele no side.id ?

site.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Site">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="site in sites" href="#/app/conteudoDoSite/{{site.id}}">
        <span ng-bind-html="site.title"></span><span class="badge badge-assertive">{{site.post_count}}</span>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

como passar parametro para outra tela com ionic1 e angular1 ? Alguem poderia me ajudar? o que estou tentando fazer é que quando o usuario clicar um desses botões seja passado o id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode obter a informação manualmente chamando um método pelo `ng-click`:

```
<button class="botao button button-positive" id="1" ng-click="getId(1)">Icon</button>
```

Depois, pode armazenar esta informação em uma variável:

```
function getId(id) {
  $scope.id = id;
  //ou, se não estiver usando $scope:
  //this.id = id;
}
```

E, por fim, enviá-la por `$stateParams` ou `$broadcast`. Para enviar por `$stateParams`, é necessário configurar as rotas de forma a considerar o parâmetro. Por exemplo, para a view `site`:

```
$stateProvider
.state('site', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/site',
    templateUrl: 'pages/site/site.html',
    controller: 'SiteCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'site',
    params: {
      id: null
    }
});
```

Aí é só enviar o parâmetro com `$state.go('site', { id: $scope.id })` e receber com `$stateParams.id` no destino.

Para o `$broadcast` o processo é um pouco mais complicado, pois necessita que haja um listener ativo no destino (o que pode não ocorrer no seu caso).

Comment: muito obrigado pela dica eu consegui fazer desse jeito : <ion-item class="col text-center">
                  <img class="botao" src="img/picture.png" ui-sref="app.conteudoDoSite({siteId: 8})"></img> 
                  <br>Galeria de <br>Fotos <br>
                </ion-item> o meu routes.js :  .state('app.conteudoDoSite', {
    url: '/conteudoDoSite/:siteId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/conteudoDoSite.html',
        controller: 'conteudoController'
      }
    }
  })

Comment: eu coloquei direto o id funciono desse jeito, eu pensei em fazer como voce sugeriu, mas eu não sabia como poderia fazer. Muito obrigado pelas dicas. @GabrielLovetro